# Why is void f(...) not allowed in C?

Tags: c, variable-length

Why doesn't C allow a function with variable length argument list such as:

```
void f(...)
{
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: Pre-standard C allowed such functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the motivation for the requirement that varargs functions must have a named parameter is for uniformity of `va_start`. For ease of implementation, `va_start` takes the name of the last named parameter. With a typical varargs calling convention, and depending on the direction arguments are stored, `va_arg` will find the first vararg at address `(&parameter_name) + 1` or `(first_vararg_type*)(&parameter_name) - 1`, plus or minus some padding to ensure alignment.

I don't think there's any particular reason why the language *couldn't* support varargs functions with no named parameters. There would have to be an alternative form of `va_start` for use in such functions, that would have to get the first vararg directly from the stack pointer (or to be pedantic the frame pointer, which is in effect the value that the stack pointer had on function entry, since the code in the function might well have moved the sp since function entry). That's possible in principle -- any implementation should have access to the stack[*] somehow, at some level -- but it might be annoying for some implementers. Once you know the varargs calling convention you can generally implement the `va_` macros without any other implementation-specific knowledge, and this would require *also* knowing how to get at the call arguments directly. I have implemented those varargs macros before, in an emulation layer, and it would have annoyed me.

Also, there's not a lot of practical use for a varargs function with no named parameters. There's no language feature for a varargs function to determine the type and number of variable arguments, so the callee has to know the type of the first vararg anyway in order to read it. So you might as well make it a named parameter with a type. In `printf` and friends the *value* of the first parameter tells the function what the *types* are of the varargs, and how many of them there are.

I suppose that in theory the callee could look at some global to figure out how to read the first argument (and whether there even is one), but that's pretty nasty. I would certainly not go out of my way to support that, and adding a new version of `va_start` with extra implementation burden is going out of my way.

[*] or if the implementation doesn't use a stack, to whatever it uses instead to pass function arguments.

Comment: Unix `<varargs.h>` (a predecessor and inspirer for the standard facility) allowed only variable arguments.  The C rationale states that the possibility of having fixed types arguments before the varargs is an innovation of the standardization process. I'll also note that C++ allows having no fixed type argument, and that the only use I've seen for it was in template meta-programming contexts.

Comment: I think *"...so the callee has to know the type of the first vararg anyway in order to read it."* is the key insight here.

Answer (score 9):

With variable-length argument list you must declare the type of the first argument - that's the syntax of the language.

```
void f(int k, ...)
{
    /* do something */
}
```

will work just fine.  You then have to use `va_list`, `va_start`, `va_end`, etc. inside the function to access individual arguments.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer by someone who actually read the question and explained why it wasn't allowed.

Comment: @WTP: strictly speaking, "...for being the *first* answer by someone who actually read [...], and *made that clear*"

Comment: imo "because it's syntax" is not an explanation, just a statement of a fact.

Comment: Consider the Münchhausen trilemma.

Comment: @Aleks: All of your answer is information only, it's the definition of var arg list usage in C, not an answer to my question. C++ supports void f(...); without a problem!

Answer (score 1):

C does allow for variable length arguments, but you need to use [va_list, va_start, va_end, etc.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_arg/) for it. How do you think [printf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) and friends are implemented? That said, I would recommend against it. You can usually accomplish a similar thing more cleanly using an array or struct for the parameters.

Comment: And `va_start` needs a function parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with it, made this nice implementation that I think some people might want to consider.

```
template<typename T>
void print(T first, ...)
{
    va_list vl;
    va_start(vl, first);
    T temp = first;
    do
    {
        cout << temp << endl;
    }
    while (temp = va_arg(vl, T));
    va_end(vl);
}
```

It ensures you have one variable minimum, but allows you to put them all in a loop in a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

There's no an intrisic reason why C can't accept void f(...). It could, but "designers" of this C feature decided not to do so.

My speculation about their motivations is that allowing void f(...) would require more "hidden" code (that can be accounted as a runtime) than not allowing it: in order to make distinguishable the case f() from f(arg) (and the others), C should provide a way to count how many args are given, and this needs more generated code (and likely a new keyword or a special variable like say "nargs" to retrieve the count), and C usually tries to be as minimalist as possible.

Answer (score -2):

The `...` allows for no arguments, ie: for `int printf(const char *format, ...);` the statement

```
printf("foobar\n");
```

is valid.

If you don't mandate at least 1 parameter (which should be used to check for more parameters), there is no way for the function to "know" how it was called.

All these statements would be valid

```
f();
f(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
f("foobar\n");
f(qsort);
```